# what happens when I copy a checked out code folder under CVS?

Tags: version-control, cvs

- I am working with a CVS repository found on a remote server.
- I check out the code to a local directory code_local
- Then I copy code_local, into code_local_2

Do I have now two independent local copies of the repository? Can I change files, commit, update etc. on each directory independently, is if it was done form two different computers?

(this may depend on the way CVS stores information about a local copy)

Yes I do know it's not a straight forward use of CVS, just asking if it will work

Comment: > the two local copies will act as (almost) two users on two computers. Yes, those two copies will act like two different users on two different computers working on the same files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have now two independent local copies of the repository?

Yes you have two independent **LOCAL** copies.

> Can I change files, commit, update etc. on each directory
>   independently?

No, both copies point to the same file on the same repository. so they are independent as long as you haven't committed them. when committed the last commit operation will overwrite the previous one.

in fact there is a `CVS` folder beside every folder of your code that keep repository information of files inside that folder. so when you copy a project or a package, the CVS folder will be copied along with, so the same repository entries will be referenced, no matter how many copies have you made.

Even if you past the copied folder to another package hierarchy, whenever you commit the files it will replace the original files in repository where it first created.

If you want to have independent copies you have to copy and place your source code (.java) files only and commit it through Eclipse for example, in this case the CVS plug-in doesn't find any existing CVS folder beside the new folder and generates a new one in the local and new entries in the repository.

Comment: Mostafa, thanks, by independently i mean that the two *local* copies, act as if they were placed on two different computers (and maybe even diffeten users). So for example if I changed both code_local/myfile and code_local2/myfile, localy, I can commit code_local/myfile than update code_local2, and then will need to merge. I.E. the two local copies will act as (almost) two users on two computers.